# How to port classregtree from Matlab to Octave?

Tags: matlab, statistics, octave

For a project, I have to make Matlab's classregtree work in Octave.

According to the docs, it is not ported yet.

I am thinking of doing it, but matlab's classregtree is a class (object oriented) with properties and methods, and I have no idea how to get this written in Octave.

Did somebody port it already? Or how do I define classes in octave (with properties and methods)?

Comment: There is classdef support in the default(development) branch. I really would suggest to move this question to the help@octave.org mailinglist where you might get more feedback. Please include the link to this initial posting

Comment: Is it? I downloaded the source of octave and forge .. and nothing.

Comment: @Jdruiter Here are instructions to get the development sources http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/get-involved.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `classregtree` with what is now called the "old-style matlab classes". In this style, all methods are simple Octave function files within a `@class-name` directory. The constructor is a function file with the same name as the class.

See the documentation on the [Octave manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Object-Oriented-Programming.html).

Also, that function seems to be deprecated in Matlab, and they recommend use of `fitctree` or `fitrtree` which will probably require classdef. You could ask your teacher about building Octave development from source and write the new version ;)